# Java | Apache POI | How to avoid null pointer exception without creating a row

Tags: java, excel, nullpointerexception, apache-poi, overwrite

I am stuck in a deadlock situation here.

I have values stored in an ArrayList.
Each value is a string, which is concat of few other strings separated by a delimiter (##).

> Eg: ArrayList ***lst*** has following 4 values.
>
> 1. **aaa**##**bbb**##**ccc**##
> 2. **d**##**ee**##**ffdfg**##
> 3. **w**##**xx**##**zzzzz**##
> 4. **mmmm**##**n**##**ooo**##

I am iterating in a for-loop, for ***lst***.size(), and fetching each value at once. Where, I am splitting the string and storing it into a String Array.

> erow = **aaa**##**bbb**##**ccc**##
>
> String[] arry = erow.split("**##**");

Within this for-loop, I am using another for-loop, for **arry**.length() to fetch each of the string (like **aaa**) and write it into a cell on excel, using Apache POI.
Finally, I want **aaa** in cell A1 of excel, **bbb** in cell B1, **ccc** in cell C1, **d** in cell A2, so on.

The problem I am facing is, after every iteration, values in previous column (A1 to A4, B1 to B4 etc.) is being erased. At the end, only C1 to C4 values remain.

I have used CreateRow and CreateCell methods.
If i use getRow and getCell methods, I am getting NullPointerException!

If I use an excel that has some data in A1 through C4 cells, and use getRow, getCell and setCellValue methods, things work splendidly. The **aaa**, **bbb** values are being written onto corresponding cells.

But every time i can't use excel with existing data. I want data to be written onto new excel file.
If the excel doesn't have any data, getCell, getRow methods throw NPE.

Please help.. how can i resolve this?

---

### Main()

```
xlo.createExcel(xlPath, xl_name, tabName,".xls");
for(int s=0;s<vals.size();s++)
{
   erow = vals.get(s);
   String[] cval = erow.split("###");

   for(int c=0; c<cval.length;c++)
   {
      xlo.writeExcel(xlPath+"/"+xl_name, tabName, s, c, cval[c]);
      System.out.println(cval[c]);
   }
   System.out.println();                        
}

System.out.println("File created ---> "+xl_name+"\n");
```

---

### WriteExcel()

```
public void writeExcel(String xlPath, String xlSheet, int rowNum, int cellNum, String inputString) throws Exception 
{
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(xlPath);
    Workbook wb =  WorkbookFactory.create(fis);
    Sheet sh = wb.getSheet(xlSheet);
    Row row = sh.createRow(rowNum);
    Cell cell=row.createCell(cellNum);

    CellStyle cs = wb.createCellStyle();
    //cs.setWrapText(true);
    cell.setCellStyle(cs);

    cell.setCellValue(inputString);
    FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream(xlPath);
    wb.write(fos);
    wb.close();
    fos.close();

}
```

---

### CreateExcel()

```
public void createExcel(String path, String fileName, String tabName, String fileExtn) throws Exception 
{
    Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
    workbook.createSheet(tabName);
    FileOutputStream fileOut;
    try 
    {
        fileOut = new FileOutputStream(path+"/"+fileName+fileExtn);
        workbook.write(fileOut);

        fileOut.close();
        workbook.close();
    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        System.out.println("Excel not created!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Call `sheet.getRow`, test for null, then call `sheet.createRow` only if needed?

Answer (score 2):

I've had to do exactly this before (but with a `,` delimiter).  Here's the reduced version of that code for `##`:

```
private XSSFWorkbook writeToExcel(LinkedHashMap<Integer, String> formattedReport) {
    try {
        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
        XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet();
        int rowIndex = sheet.getLastRowNum();
        Set<Integer> keySet = formattedReport.keySet();
        for (Integer key : keySet) {
            XSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(rowIndex++);
            String line = formattedReport.get(key);
            String[] strArr = line.split("##");

            int cellCount = 0;
            for (String str : strArr) {
                XSSFCell cell = row.createCell(cellCount++);
                cell.setCellValue(str);
            }
        }

        return workbook;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null; //or return new XSSFWorkbook();
}
```

This should work as you want it to.  It uses a Map so you'll have to change it to use `ArrayList` but it should function no differently.

Comment: I tried your approach. Yet the same result :(
I have added my code above. Can you please suggest what changes I should do in writeExcel()

Comment: You need to write to the sheet, which means you need to save it to the variable.